# F# SqlProvider - how to access stored procedure results?

Tags: f#, type-providers

I am using SQLProvider from NuGet (https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLProvider/ v1.1.42) in an F# project to access our MSSQL database.

I am referring to the sample code from here, https://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/core/programmability.html and also the source code tests on GitHub, https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider/blob/master/tests/SqlProvider.Tests/scripts/MySqlTests.fsx.

```
#r @"....\packages\SQLProvider.1.1.42\lib\net451\FSharp.Data.SqlProvider.dll"
#r @"....\System.Data.Linq.dll"

open System
open FSharp.Data.Sql
open FSharp.Data.Sql.Common
open System.Data.Linq

type SeriesResult = { .. fields .. }

[<Literal>]
let ConnectionString = @"connStr"

type Sql = SqlDataProvider<
                    ConnectionString = ConnectionString,
                    DatabaseVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER>

let db = Sql.GetDataContext()

let test = 
    [
        for f in db.Procedures.MyStoredProcedure.Invoke("param").ResultSet do
            yield f.MapTo<SeriesResult>()
    ]
```

I need to access results from the call to MyStoredProcedure, but `ResultSet` errors with `error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'ResultSet' is not defined"`.  I also get this for ColumnValues, and on MapTo (presumably because the type is unknown).

Is there an additional library I should be referencing?

I have: FSharp.Core, FSharp.Data, FSharp.Data.SqlProvider, mscorelib, System, System.Core, System.Data, System.Data.Linq, System.Xml.Linq

Thanks!

(wanted to tag with SQLProvider - but can't!)

Comment: So this is weird...  I added an open for each of my referenced dlls, and Visual Studio finally recognised ResultSet.  Wanting to know which reference it was, I removed them all - it's been working since!  Even after multiple cleans and bin deleting, it may have just been a VS quirk.  Would still be interested if anyone can shed any light on this, as it seems common with F#.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason for this is that the intelli-sense thread probably timed out waiting for a response from the SQL provider.

The stored procs and the set of types to carry the result `ResultSet` are computed lazily (when you type the `.`). This is good in one way as it means the provider doesn't introspect the entire database on instantiation, pulling in lots of stuff you're probably not going to use. However it does have the side effect, of needing to do a non-trivial amount of work in the `.` completion on the first request, we cache the result after that. I believe Microsoft have a metric that says any intelli-sense work should complete in 250ms, but what the actual thread timeout is I'm not sure. With a language like C# and F# hitting a response target of 250ms can be a big ask on large solutions, but throw a database in the mix (even a small local database) this becomes a very hard target to hit.

Quite why it didn't recover and try again until you added the references, will only be known to Visual Studio; Usually however just closing and re-opening the file is enough. In rare cases unload the project from the solution and reload.